# How to use definition with experimental annotation in my code without repeat the annotation?

Tags: scala

For example: `MacroAnnotation` in scala 3.3 is experimental, ref to it will infect to every where in the code.

So, is there some workaround to silent the experimental compilation error, like compiler config or other magic?

Answer (score 0):

There is no official workaround and it is on purpose: the idea is that you might want to use some functionality to test and maybe provide feedback BUT since these features might break or get completely removed community should be discouraged from using them everywhere. If you want to use it, you will have to slap `@experimental` annotation everywhere, and the more you use it the more you should be reminded that you shouldn't ship it in a production code.

I've found a workaround for avoiding this flag when I call an experimental method (cough, reflection, cough), but I wouldn't advertise such tricks, as you are setting your users up for failure.